# MySQL query run time is too long (simple LEFT JOIN)

Tags: mysql, join, runtime

I've came across the following problem, for no apparent reason. I have 2 tables:

`isrc` (about 23k rows):

```
Field           Type           Null    Default    Extra
isrc_ID         int(11)         NO      PRI     auto_increment
ISRC            varchar(25)     NO      UNI     
Track_Name      varchar(255)    YES         
Track_Time      time            YES     00:00:00    
ArtistName      varchar(255)    YES         
TitleVersion    varchar(255)    YES         
Date_update     timestamp       NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

`isrc_performer` (901 rows):

```
Field               Type           Null    Default    Extra
Perf_ID             int(11)         NO      PRI     auto_increment
isrc_ID             int(11)         NO          
PerformerName       varchar(255)    YES         
PerformerCategory   varchar(255)    YES         
PerformerRole       varchar(255)    YES         
date_update         timestamp       NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And the following simple query runs too long:

```
SELECT          
isrc.ISRC,  
isrc.Track_Name,    
isrc.ArtistName,
isrc.TitleVersion,
isrc.Track_Time,
`isrc_performer`.`PerformerName` ,
`isrc_performer`.`PerformerCategory` ,
`isrc_performer`.`PerformerRole` ,
`isrc`.`isrc_ID`,
`isrc_performer`.`Perf_ID`

FROM `isrc`

LEFT JOIN `isrc_performer` ON (isrc_performer.isrc_ID = isrc.isrc_ID)

ORDER BY   isrc_ID     desc LIMIT 0 , 10
```

run time - 5.117 sec

Individual requests to each table:

```
SELECT 
isrc.ISRC,
isrc.Track_Name,
isrc.ArtistName,
isrc.TitleVersion,
isrc.Track_Time

FROM `isrc`

ORDER BY   isrc_ID     desc LIMIT 0 , 10
```

run time - 0.000 sec

```
SELECT      
`isrc_performer`.`PerformerName` ,
`isrc_performer`.`PerformerCategory` ,
`isrc_performer`.`PerformerRole`,
`isrc_performer`.`Perf_ID`

FROM `isrc_performer`

ORDER BY   Perf_ID     desc LIMIT 0 , 10
```

run time - 0.000 sec

Can someone with a fresh eye point me to the right direction as why this could be?

Comment: Are there any indexes? You need one on isrc_performer.isrc_ID.

Comment: The `DESCRIBE` output shows that there's no index on `isrc_performer.isrc_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index to the `isrc_performer` table:

```
ALTER TABLE isrc_performer ADD INDEX (isrc_ID);
```

Otherwise it has to perform a full scan of the table to find the rows with a matching `isrc_ID` when joining.

Comment: Oh of course! simple as that. forgot about indexing.... very important that is...

Comment: Move to a NoSQL engine... just kidding.. add an index.